# JSONEncoder.encode produces: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in case of inheritance

Tags: json, swift, xcode, encoding

To communicate to my Server I am using Objects of `NetworkMessages`:

```
class NetworkMessage: Codable {

    var version:Int?;

    required init() {

    }

}


class AddPlayerRequest: NetworkMessage {

    var playerName: String?;
    var playerHashedPw:String?;


}
```

I am now trying to encode my Object to a String to send it over the network to my Server:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let data = try! encoder.encode(netMsg)
let stringToSend = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
/* and send the string to the Server here... */
```

Now when I try to send a Object of Type `NetworkMessage` everything works fine, but when I am using a subclass of `NetworkMessage`, in this case a `CreatePlayerRequest`, this error gets thrown:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

at this line:

```
let data = try! encoder.encode(netMsg)
```

Thanks for your help!

******* UPDATE *******

**I now copied your code and get the error in another line (see Comment):**

```
do {
        let netMsg = AddPlayerRequest()
        netMsg.playerName = "Test"
        netMsg.playerHashedPw = "hynt87t7t76yt=="


        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let data = try encoder.encode(netMsg) /* Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS */
        let stringToSend = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        print(stringToSend ?? "")
    } catch {
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: `try!` says "I am asserting that there will not be an error here. If there is, please terminate my program." Consider `do { let data = try encoder.encode(...) } catch { ... }` to catch the error and inspect it to see what went wrong.

Comment: Yes I know what try! does and I implemented it as you suggested in my App, I only changed it here to make it not to complex.

Comment: So... what does the error say? :) That’s a critical piece of information to include here.

Comment: How can I see addional error informations?

Comment: You can always `do { ... } catch { print(error) }` to get more info about what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

In case of inheritance you have to implement the `Coding` itself. So you need to specify `CodingKeys` and implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`.

[There is a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5125).

So you can change your classes like this and it will work:

```
class NetworkMessage: Codable {
    var version:Int?
}


class AddPlayerRequest: NetworkMessage {

    var playerName: String?
    var playerHashedPw:String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case playerName; case playerHashedPw }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(playerName, forKey: .playerName)
        try container.encode(playerHashedPw, forKey: .playerHashedPw)

        try super.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
let netMsg = AddPlayerRequest()
netMsg.playerName = "Test"
netMsg.playerHashedPw = "hynt87t7t76yt=="
netMsg.version = 1

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(netMsg)
    let stringToSend = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

    print(stringToSend ?? "")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "version" : 1,
  "playerHashedPw" : "hynt87t7t76yt==",
  "playerName" : "Test"
}
```

Comment: Then the resulting string is {} and the properties are missing for some reason :(

Comment: @julien-100000 I have added the test code with output I'm getting.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I copied your code and the StringtoSend ist still "{}". I do not understand why...

Comment: I copied your code now and got another error in another line, where I just set a variable. I really do not understand how that can produce the error.... Maybe you have an idea? Thanks for your help. I marked the new error with "***UPDATE***"